# How to restore deleted user

Tags: getstream-io

I  deleted the user. Code below

```
return $this->getStream->delete('5');
```

And now each connection with this user id returned error

```
"{\"code\":16,\"message\":\"UpdateUsers failed with error: \\\"user 5 was deleted\\\"\",\"StatusCode\":404,\"duration\":\"0.00ms\"}"
```

How to restore this deleted user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once deleted, it is not possible to restore a user ID on Stream